# How to relate between Random Variable, Probability mass/density function and Probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

While studying probability I came across these terms Random variable, probability function, and probability distribution. How to relate these these 3 terms in unfair coin toss problem where head probability is “p” in a binomial distribution with n trials

Comment: As it stands the question is too broad. I think you should take an example of a random variable for which you struggle to understand the probability function/distribution.

Comment: I changed the question for a coin toss problem